# Twig conditional around form-group input value

Tags: header, twig

very new to Twig and im trying to build a conditional to render if a form group with a nested input meets a specific value, else do something different. Here is the code, but it doe not seem to be rendering correctly when specific parameters are met. Am I doing this correctly? Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

```
{% set RespHeader %}{{ form-group.input.value }}{% endset %}
{% if RespHeader == "Something" %}
<header id="header" class="responsive-section-label">
{% else %}
<header id="header" class="section-label">    
{% endif %}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Twig will translate your `form-group` variable as `form minus group`.
Either don't use dashes or use the array notation e.g.

```
{% set RespHeader %}{{ _context['form-group'].input.value }}{% endset %}
```

---

*note: `_context` is a special variable which contains all known variables to the template*